# Eclipse server location using workspace metadata, can't change to installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment, eclipse-wtp

I want Eclipse deploy my application to Tomcat installation folder's webapps when I add it to server in Eclipse, but for some reason Eclipse seems to use it's internal server instance under `.metadata/.plugins`, even thought I added my server manually and provided the installation directory. After that I added the server runtime to project facets and enabled `dynamic web module`. Now when I add the application to server under server tab and start the server, application doesn't appear in Tomcats installation folder nor is the instance started up.

When I look the server configuration tab, I can see Eclipse is using *workspace metadata for server location* and doesn't let me change it to tomcat installation.

[image]

What is causing the problem and how to solve it? I have spent hours with this one with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all modules in the server configuration/Modules tab.
2. Close the configuration.
3. Right click the server in the "Servers" view and publish it.
4. Open the configuration again.

Then it must be editable.

Comment: This works to the point, where server deploys application (I can see it in manager). However, when I try to load the page I get error 403 access forbidden. If I deploy the war file manually, it load normally, and goes to different context path than eclipse deploy.